# iPhone 6 with iOS 9.3.5 sends wrong os version in the user agent from UIWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, user-agent

I am trying to load a web page in UIWebview. The URL request contains following user agent:

```
"User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.23 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602";
```

When I try lo load the same with safari browser the user agent is:

```
 "User-Agent" = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13G36 Safari/601.1";
```

The os version is 10_3 instead of 9_3_5.

How to resolve this issue. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you possibly set a custom UserAgent? If so try to reset it like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] volatileDomainForName:NSRegistrationDomain].mutableCopy;
[mDict removeObjectForKey:@"UserAgent"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setVolatileDomain:mDict forName:NSRegistrationDomain];
```